# Visual Studio 2010 - Is there a way to change the <General> and <Declarations> dropdowns in VB to act like the C# dropdowns?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Heres a screenshot.

[image]

Essentially, in C# the left dropdown has all the classes in a file while the right drop down has all the methods, events, properties, etc.

In VB all of my controls are in the left dropdown and I have to select them if I want to go to a particular event handler for that control.

I find it time consuming to navigate to my btnSave_Click method by first selecting btnSave in the left dropdown and then selecting Click in the right dropdown.

Is there a setting or a plugin that can change this functionality?

Comment: Have you experimented with any of the environment settings?  I don't have VS on me, but I know when you first run it, it asks you about your IDE setup, and where you want things.

Comment: Yeah, I've gone through them. There are only 7 VB specific options and all relate to coding. I guess it would help if I knew what the correct names of the dropdowns were.

Comment: I would be surprised if there wasn't a way to do that. Have you looked through all of the general and language-inspecific settings to see if there's an option for that somewhere?

Comment: @JamesJohnson Yup, I browsed the whole tree. Nothing really stood out. :/

Comment: I found the same issue in VS 2010, I find it easiest and fastest just to double click on the control in the design view to get to double click event for that control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really has more to do with the differences in how events are linked to control events in VB.Net versus C#, and specifically the Handles statement in VB.Net.

If you assign your methods to the control events at runtime like C# does rather than using the Handles statement in VB.Net, then all of your methods will appear in the right-hand dropdown within VB. This also applies to any member variables that you have declared as WithEvents.